# Prove that $\vec{r}(t)=c\int_a^t y(u) \times y'(u) du$ has constant curvature.

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose that $y: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a continuous function parametrized by arclength and suppose $y,y',y''$ are linearly independent in $[a,b]$.

Define the curve $\vec{r}(t)=c\int_a^t y(u) \times y'(u) du$ where $c$ is a non zero constant.Prove that $r$ has constant curvature. Is the opposite true?

I am preparing for an exam and stumbled on the problem above. I really have no idea how to approach it.

Comment: This problem is incorrect. I was suspicious when I saw it, because the "standard" exercise assumes $\|y\|=1$ and asks to show that *torsion* is constant. Using the standard formula for curvature of a non-arclength-parametrized curve ($\kappa = \|\vec r'\times\vec r''\|/\|\vec r'\|^3$), it is not hard to see that the problem can't be right by considering the effect of stretching $y$ by a constant factor (and adjusting the parametrization accordingly). But, just to be sure, I had Mathematica do the calculation when $y$ parametrizes a standard helix, and, indeed, curvature is *not* constant.

Comment: It is said that the function is parametrized by arclength so you are right that $||y||=1$. I solved it by using the formula for $\kappa$ that you mentioned so it must be correct. Thanks

Comment: No, if $y$ is parametrized by arclength, that means that $\|y'\|=1$. I don't believe you solved it :)